# Get date and time of max value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weather-reading database where I store all data for consumption by a webpage that shows the MAX and MIN pressure.

The problem is that I like to show the time and date in which these values where recorded.

Code I use to read MAX pressure:

```
$max_out_pressure = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(out_pressure) AS out_pressure FROM $table");
$max_out_pressure = mysql_result($max_out_pressure,0,"out_pressure");
$max_out_pressure = substr($max_out_pressure, 0, 6);
echo "$max_out_pressure";
echo "mbar";
```

I have the columns `ID`, `Datetime`, `Pressure`, `Temperature` 
Table is named `readings`

Webpage: http://temperatur.co.nf/readings.php

Never made an database or webpage before, so I`m struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the maximum pressure and the date it was recorded.

```
$sql = "SELECT out_pressure, Datetime
        FROM $table
        ORDER BY out_pressure DESC
        LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$max_out_pressure = $row['out_pressure'];
$max_date = $row['Datetime'];
```

Comment: $Max_date = mysql_query("SELECT out_pressure, date FROM $table ORDER BY out_pressure DESC LIMIT 1");
                            echo "$Max_date";

Comment: I wrote: $Max_date = mysql_query("SELECT out_pressure, date FROM $table ORDER BY out_pressure DESC LIMIT 1");
                            echo "$Max_date";

Comment: `mysql_query` doesn't return the data from the table, you have to use `mysql_fetch_XXX` or `mysql_result` to get that.

Comment: Sorry the mess. I can not press "return without appying the message, (strange!)       I wrote:    $Max_date = mysql_query("SELECT out_pressure, date FROM $table ORDER BY out_pressure DESC LIMIT 1");
                            echo "$Max_date";      This gives me just "Resource id #11"

Comment: You can't put formatted text in comments. Add it to the question.

Comment: From your question, it looked like you know how to read the results from a query. But I guess not. I added it to the answer.